# Proving that $0 \leq k \sin\left(\frac{2\pi}{n}\right) - \sin\left(\frac{2\pi k}{n}\right)$

Tags: trigonometry, inequality

I need help proving that

$$
0 \leq k \sin\left(\frac{2\pi}{n}\right) - \sin\left(\frac{2\pi k}{n}\right)
$$
For $n > 2$ and positive $k$.

I've tried all sorts of identities, and nothing have worked. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

The things I have tried are the following:

Using a identity for multiples angle formula:

$$
k\sin \left(\frac{2 \pi}{n}\right)  >\sin\left(k\cdot\frac{2 \pi }{n}\right)=2^{k -1}\prod_{i=0}^{k-1}\sin \left(\frac{\pi i}{k}+\frac{2 \pi }{n}\right)
$$

$$
k \geq 2^{k -1}\prod_{i=1}^{k-1}\sin \left(\frac{\pi i}{k}+\frac{2 \pi }{n}\right)
$$
Which I could not make sense of.

I also tried rewriting the inequality
$$
k\sin \left(\frac{2 \pi}{n}\right)  +\sin \left(\frac{2 \pi (n -k)}{n}\right)>0
$$
Which got me here:
$$\begin{split}
&=(k-1)\sin \left(\frac{2 \pi}{n}\right)+\sin \left(\frac{2 \pi}{n}\right)+\sin \left(\frac{2 \pi (n -k)}{n}\right)\\
&=(k-1)\sin \left(\frac{2 \pi}{n}\right)+2\sin \left(\frac12\left[\frac{2 \pi}{n}+\frac{2 \pi (n -k)}{n}\right]\right)\sin \left(\frac12\left[\frac{2 \pi}{n}-\frac{2 \pi (n -k)}{n}\right]\right)
\end{split}$$

But I could not make that work either.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Hint: $sin(x)\leq x$ for $x \geq 0$

Comment: @Keine_Maschine can you elaborate on that? This shows me that 
 k*\sin(2\pi/n) <= k* 2\pi/n
and
sin(2 \pi k/n ) <= 2\pi k /n
But I cannot see how that helps me

Comment: You can have a look at a proof of this equation and try to prove from there on $sin(xy)\leq sin(x)y$ for $\pi>x>0;y>0$. Btw I don't know whether this holds but it seems like a reasonable ansatz to me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am assuming that $k,n\in\mathbb{Z}$.

Suppose that for some $k$, we have
$$
\sin\left(\frac{2\pi k}{n}\right)\le k\sin\left(\frac{2\pi}{n}\right)\tag1
$$
Note that $(1)$ is trivially true for $k=1$.

For $k\ge2$, we have
$$
k\,\overbrace{\sin\left(\frac{2\pi}4\right)}^1\gt k\,\overbrace{\sin\left(\frac{2\pi}3\right)}^{\sqrt3/2}\gt1\ge\overbrace{\sin\left(\frac{2\pi k}{n}\right)}^{\le1}\tag2
$$
Thus, $(1)$ is true for $n=3$ and $n=4$. Therefore, assume, $n\ge5$.
$$
\begin{align}
\sin\left(\frac{2\pi(k+1)}{n}\right)
&=\sin\left(\frac{2\pi k}{n}\right)\cos\left(\frac{2\pi}{n}\right)+\cos\left(\frac{2\pi k}{n}\right)\sin\left(\frac{2\pi}{n}\right)\tag{3a}\\
&\le k\sin\left(\frac{2\pi}{n}\right)\cos\left(\frac{2\pi}{n}\right)+\cos\left(\frac{2\pi k}{n}\right)\sin\left(\frac{2\pi}{n}\right)\tag{3b}\\
&=\left(k\cos\left(\frac{2\pi}{n}\right)+\cos\left(\frac{2\pi k}{n}\right)\right)\sin\left(\frac{2\pi}{n}\right)\tag{3c}\\
&\le(k+1)\sin\left(\frac{2\pi}{n}\right)\tag{3d}
\end{align}
$$
$\text{(3a):}$ sine of a sum identity
$\text{(3b):}$ apply $(1)$ with $\cos\left(\frac{2\pi}n\right)\ge\cos\left(\frac{2\pi}5\right)=\frac{-1+\sqrt5}4$
$\text{(3c):}$ distribute a product over a sum
$\text{(3d):}$ $\cos(x)\le1$ and $\sin\left(\frac{2\pi}n\right)\ge0$ for $n\ge2$

Inequality $(1)$ is true for $k=1$. Then $(3)$ and induction prove $(1)$ for any $k\ge1$.

Comment: Thank you so much, this is brilliant! :D

Comment: Where do you use that n>2? If for example n =1 the inequality is not true.

Comment: Was $k$ limited to natural numbers?  If so, in future you should make that clearer in the problem statement

Comment: I have found the mistake. Here is an example of the same mistake, in a more obvious way:
$$
-5 \leq 1
$$
so
$$
500 =(-5)\cdot(-100) \leq 1\cdot(-100) = -100
$$
Which is not true. So we have to assume that n > 2, so that we do not multiply negative numbers before we apply (1)

Comment: I have added to step $\text{(2d)}$ where we use that $n\ge3$. However, if $n=1$ or $n=2$, $\sin\left(\frac{2\pi}n\right)=0$ and the problem does not occur.  It would only occur if $n\lt2$ and $n$ was not an integer.

Comment: @Alan I made that assumption in the first line since Kinkin used $$\prod_{i=1}^{k-1}\sin\left(\frac{\pi i}k+\frac{2\pi}n\right)$$ and that usually means $k$ is an integer.

Answer (score 1):

Assume $0 < k \le 1$ and $n \ge 4$. Put $x = \dfrac{2\pi k}{n} \implies k = \dfrac{nx}{2\pi}$. Thus you prove: $\dfrac{\sin\left(\frac{2\pi}{n}\right)}{\frac{2\pi}{n}} \le \dfrac{\sin x}{x}$. But the function $ f(x) = \dfrac{\sin x}{x}$ on $\left(0,\frac{2\pi}{n}\right]$ has $f’(x) = \dfrac{x\cdot \cos x - \sin x}{x^2} < 0$ since $\tan x > x$ on this same domain of $x$. Thus $f$ is a decreasing function and you have $f(x) \ge f\left(\frac{2\pi}{n}\right)$ since $0 < x < \frac{2\pi}{n}$. Done.
Note:The inequality reverses when $k < 1$.

Answer (score 1):

It is a consequence of convexity of $\sin$ on $[0,\pi]$*. The straight line from $(0,0)$ to $(x,\sin(x))$ passes through the point $(x/k,\sin(x)/k)$. Therefore, we have $\sin(x)/k\le \sin(x/k)$. Now set $x=\frac{2\pi k}{n}$.

*We must have $x\in [0,\pi]$ to use convexity, so this unfortunately only gives the result for $n\ge2k$.

Answer (score 1):

*Alternative proof*:

Assume that $k \in \mathbb{Z}$.

**Fact 1**: Let $k\in \mathbb{Z}_{\ge 1}$. Then,
$k \sin x - \sin (k x) \ge 0$ for all $x \in [0, \pi]$.

By Fact 1, letting $x = \frac{2\pi}{n} \in (0, \pi)$, the desired result follows.

---

*Proof of Fact 1*:

Let $f(x) := k\sin x - \sin (kx)$.
We have $f(0) = f(\pi) = 0$.

Assume, for the sake of contradiction, that there exists $a \in (0, \pi)$ such that $k \sin a - \sin (ka) < 0$.
Let $x_0$ be the global minimizer of $f(x)$ on $[0, \pi]$.
Then we have $f(x_0) < 0$ and $f'(x_0) = 0$, i.e.,
\begin{align*}
 k\sin x_0 &< \sin (kx_0),\\
 k\cos x_0 &= k \cos (kx_0)
\end{align*}
which results in
\begin{align*}
 k^4\sin^2 x_0 &< k^2\sin^2 (kx_0),\\
 k^2\cos^2 x_0 &= k^2 \cos^2 (kx_0).
\end{align*}
Adding them up, we have
$k^4 \sin^2 x_0 + k^2 \cos^2 x_0 < k^2 \sin^2(kx_0) + k^2\cos^2(kx_0) = k^2$.
However, $k^4 \sin^2 x_0 + k^2 \cos^2 x_0
\ge k^2 \sin^2 x_0 + k^2 \cos^2 x_0 = k^2$.
Contradiction.

We are done.